# copy files when Docker Container starts

Tags: file, docker-compose, copy

I just made my first Docker compose for WordPress successful. That is really cool.

Since I like to repeatedly use individual plugins for WP repeatedly, I'm looking for a way of a parent folder to copy plugins into the working folder of the WordPress instance when I start the first MAl the Docker container.

Can someone give me an example of how to implement that?

Many thanks for your help
Steffen

Answer (score 0):

In your docker compose, setup `volumes`. this way on startup you can sync the `wp-contents` folder to the container's

Refer to:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference